# Can I provide a default value for an abstract type in Scala?

Tags: scala, abstract-type

I have a class like this:

```
abstract class CrudResource extends Controller {
  type ResourceIdType


  def getAction(id: ResourceIdType) = ...
  def deleteAction(id: ResourceIdType) = ...

  ...
}
```

which is intended to be used like so:

```
class Payees extends CrudResource {
  type ResourceIdType = Int

  ...
}
```

I'd like to default the `ResourceIdType` to Int, like so:

```
abstract class CrudResource extends Controller {
  type ResourceIdType = Int

  ...
}
```

so that the ID type will be `Int` unless a subclass  overrides it like so:

```
override type ResourceId = String
```

but this fails to compile with:

```
error: overriding type ResourceIdType in class CrudResource, which equals Int;
 type ResourceIdType has incompatible type
       class Payees extends CrudResource { override type ResourceIdType = String }
```

Is it possible to do what I'm trying to do? I tried, in `CrudResource`, `type ResourceIdType <: Any = Int`, but that's not valid syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would be a violation of the liskov substitution principle. Let's assume you can do it.

```
abstract class CrudResource extends Controller {
  type ResourceIdType = Int
  def resources: List[ResourceIdType] = ???
  def getAction(id: ResourceIdType) = ???
  def deleteAction(id: ResourceIdType) = ???
}

class Payees extends CrudResource {
  override type ResourceIdType = String
}

class Trouble {
  var resource: Controller.ResourceIdType
}
val trouble = new Trouble
val crudResource: CrudResource = new Payee
trouble.resource = crudResource.resources.head // assigning String to Int var!
```

However, you are halfway to a cake pattern. If you define ResourceId as an abstract nested class, you could have subclasses implementing them in terms of `Int` or `String`, as long as its API doesn't expose the specific types.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you can really do this, but generics and inheritance can do it in a nice way:

```
abstract class CrudController [T] {

    def getAction( resource : T )
    def deleteAction( resource : T )
    def updateAction( resource : T )

}

abstract class IntCrudController extends CrudController [Int]

class PayeesController extends IntCrudController {

    override def getAction( resource : Int ) {}

    def deleteAction(resource: Int) {}

    def updateAction(resource: Int) {}
}
```

Comment: Yeah, this is the closest I got, i.e. an intermediate class that provides types for the abstract types in the parent.

Answer (score 1):

No, as far as I know, this isn't possible.

Answer (score 1):

Scala's abstract type become frozen once you define it. You can't override one type with another in a inherited class